# How to create a Index to suit my both queries of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

With the system.profile collection, i was able to collect the queries that were happening on my Application .

I have got questions with respect to these below two queries which i collected from system.profile collection .

```
{ "query" : { "symbol" : "AAPL", "date" : "2013-11-29", "type" : "O"}, "orderby" : { "price" : 1 } }
```

and

```
{ query: { symbol: "AAPL", date: "2013-11-01", type: "O",  rootsymbol: "AAPL" }, orderby: { price: 1, buy_sell: 1 }
```

What is the proper way to create Index so that it will satisfy both the above queries ??

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"symbol":1,"date":1,"type": 1,"rootsymbol":1,"price":1,"buy_sell":1},{"unique" : false})


OR
```

**create 3 queries as shown below**

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"symbol":1,"date":1,"type": 1,"rootsymbol":1},{"unique" : false})

db.collection.ensureIndex({"price" : 1}, {"unique" : false})

db.collection.ensureIndex({"buy_sell" : 1}, {"unique" : false})
```

Answer (score 1):

The sledgehammer solution is to create two indexes that match your queries exactly:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "symbol" : 1, "date" : 1, "type" : 1, "price" : 1});

db.collection.ensureIndex({ "symbol" : 1, "date" : 1, "type" : 1,
                            "rootsymbol" : 1, "price" : 1, "buy_sell" : 1});
```

As you can see, the `rootsymbol` is the only reason we need a second index, so it'd be great if you could get rid of that - this depends on your data, unfortunately, so I can't help you with that. For instance, if there's only a low number of hits with different rootsymbols, it might be more efficient to filter the results client-side than to have a second index to manage.

The [documentation on sorting with indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sorting-with-indexes) comes with a set of nice examples for sort queries and explains the requirements for efficient index use on sort queries quite well.

Comment: It will be  a overhead if i create two indexes . I guess that the second query will serve both the queries as i have the order matching . what do you suggest .

Comment: why did you ask the question then? That assumption is wrong as the official docs indicate, you'll have to get rid of the `rootsymbol` or explicitly include it as a field